# Scala: Accessing case class defined in another file

Tags: scala, case-class

I have following definitions:

```
case class MyData(id: String, name: String)

object MyData {
  ....
}
```

These are in same Scala file.

How can I now access case class in another Scala file? When I try to do something like following in another Scala file:

```
implicit val dataFormat = jsonFormat2(MyData)
```

...I get error: Type mismatch, found MyData.type

Comment: so I am using spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol.jsonFormat2 from akka-http-spray-json. Btw, When I define case class in same file then it works all fine.

Comment: It seems very likely that you are actually running different code in the two cases. The specific bug you mention definitely has nothing to do with where the `case class` is defined, and everything to do with passing a type to the function rather than an object.

Comment: Try `jsonFormat2(MyData.apply)` or possibly `jsonFormat2(MyData.apply(_,_))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @jwvh's answer, if you don't define a companion object for a `case class`, the compiler-generated companion object (part of the `case class` magic) will express the presence of the `apply` method in its type, that is to say, for `MyData`

```scala
object MyData extends Function2[String, String, MyData]
```

This allows the bare companion object to be used in contexts expecting a function, e.g. to Spray's `jsonFormat2`.

If you define a companion object for the `case class` yourself, that part of the `case class` magic is suppressed (though the compiler still generates the `apply` method unless the `case class` is `abstract`), so you can either:

- Duplicate that bit of compiler magic yourself (see above)
- Partially-apply the `apply` call to turn it into a function as in

```scala
jsonFormat2(MyData.apply(_, _))
```

Comment: I suspect the reason the compiler doesn't perform this magic is to support the case where a companion object has multiple `apply` methods of the same arity, since you can't extend `Function2` twice.